# DataSet.GetChanges() return null C#

Tags: c#, ado.net

I try this

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.AcceptChanges();

//edit table in ds
ds.Tables[0].Rows.RemoveAt(0);

//get changes
DataSet ds2 = ds.GetChanges();

but ds2 is null, why?
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Delete instead of RemoveAt:

```
//ds.Tables[0].Rows.RemoveAt(0);
ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Delete();
```

RemoveAt() really removes the Row, there is no trace of it left and hence there is no Change information. Delete() just marks the row as deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the table was already empty, do removing the first row didn't change anything?

Comment: I bind dataset table in grid view, and than a i call this code